# UITable View numberOfRowsInSection & cellForRowAtIndexPath Error

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview

My problem is that I have a UITable, and I cannot get the numberOfRowsInSection to correspond with cellForRowAtIndexPath.

My foodCategoryObj has three arrays, first array has 6 elems, second has 2 and third has 3.

This line 
    FoodCategory *foodCategoryObj = [appDelegate.foodCategoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

..keeps throwing this error.. index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]

Overall I do not know what number to return for numberOfRowsInSection

Also arrayCountInt returns number of objects in the array I have created in viewWillAppear.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *arrayCountString = [prefs stringForKey:@"arrayCountString"];
NSInteger *arrayCountInt = [arrayCountString intValue];
//NSLog(@"arrayCountInt.. %i", (arrayCountInt) - 1);


AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSInteger *arrayCount = [appDelegate.foodCategoryArray count];


NSInteger *foodArray = [foodCatArray count];


// testing
NSLog(@"foodCatArray.. %i", foodArray);


return arrayCountInt;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

//NSLog(@"indexPath.row.. %i", (indexPath.row)-1);
FoodCategory *foodCategoryObj = [appDelegate.foodCategoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

//Set the cell title
cell.text = foodCategoryObj.foodName;


// testing
//NSLog(@"%@", foodCategoryObj.foodName);
//NSLog(@"appDelegate.foodCategoryArray.. %@", appDelegate.foodCategoryArray);

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Your code seems very confused - you have one array in the app delegate and another in viewDidAppear? It looks like you're returning the count of the array you say you create in viewDidAppear, but in cellForRowAtIndexPath, you are getting the data from the array in the app delegate -- that's a problem. Do you have sections in your table? If so, then you need to implement numberOfSectionsInTableView. If you don't have sections, then your data shouldn't be structured as an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you return `[appDelegate.foodCategoryArray count]` in the `numberofrowInSection` method. You should return your `foodArray` and you return the wrong var